# Add Scrollbar on Bootstrap table grid under col 12 div

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, styles

In below grid, how could I add the scrollbar.
It just using bootstrap table under bootstrap col 12 div.

I've tried with following css but it does not apply scrollbar, it just mess the columns.

```css
divgrid.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="divgrid">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead class="ui-widget-header">
        <tr>
          <th v-for="header in columns()">
            {{header.displayName }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row,index) in datasourc">
          <td v-for="column in columns" class="wrap-break-word" v-show="column.isVisible">
            <span v-html="row[column.name]"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `<table>` into a `<div class="table-responsive">`.

It might work if you simply place that class on `#divgrid`. If it doesn't, use the wrapper as specified in [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables).

**Note:** this also works on [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive).

Comment: I can see the scrollbar now but, all the column header are messed and overlapped. scrollbar is shown but mostly all the columns are fit in screen and so, it looks like all columns are overlapped.

Comment: Without a proper [mcve] I can't help you. You need to update the code in your question with the actual html markup output of your page (the source code) - you can get it by selecting "View page source" in context menu.